# Creation of Human Task with BPEL - ODE using "TaskManagerProcess.wsdl" from Intalio-BPMS-6.5.1

Tags: xml, wsdl, bpel, apache-ode

I am using Eclipse BPEL designer and ODE server. As you all know, BPEL alone does not support "Human Tasks and human task forms". I am trying to use the Tempo server from Intalio-BPMS for that purpose.

Now I want to use `createTaskRequest` request that can be sent to a service `UserBusinessProcessService` with Interface `UserBusinessProcessPortType` which is present in `TaskManagerProcess.wsdl` from Intalio-BPMS-6.5.1.  I know how to create partnerlinks and deploying the processes on ODE. When I try to start my deployed process, I get

```
{***

    fault: 
    exceptionClass:org.apache.axis2.AxisFault
    message: axis2ns1:uninitializedvariable

***}
```

and and the same exception as an error in server trace. :(

From the trace I understood that I am not properly initializing the `createTaskRequest`. I dont know how to proceed. Please guide me. Any Help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance,
Karthik

Answer (score 1):

In BPEL all variables need to be initialized first. This usually means that you create a basic skeleton XML snippet that is conformant with the schema of the variable/message type and assign it to the variable. Later on, the element or attribute values of this skeleton can be replace by actual values using XPath expressions in the to-spec of another assign. Put in other words, when you want to assign a value to a certain element of a variable, this element must be part of variable's XML content prior to the assign. Otherwise this element can be selected, which will result in a selectionFailure fault.